# Making the TreeView.ItemsPanel a Canvas

Tags: wpf, treeview, wpf-controls, wpf-positioning

I am looking for a way to make my `TreeView` display items in `Canvas` panel.

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemsPanel>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Root" IsExpanded="True" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="20">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Alpha" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="50">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Sub"/>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Beta"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Gamma"/>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

This solution allows me to move around Root `TreeViewItem`, but I want every single item in `TreeView` to respect `Canvas` attached properties. What I mean is, when Root {Left = 50, Top = 10} (to here it works) contains Alpha {Left = 0, Top=0}, Root would be at [50,10] and Alpha at [0,0] (coordinates are absolute to `Canvas`).

The reason why only Root `TreeViewItem` places itself correctly is, that I use `TreeView.ItemsPanel`. I have a feeling I should use `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle` instead, but I really don't know how.

Any help is appreciated of course, preferably incorporating `HierarchicalDataTemplate` too so _I know how to connect the solution with `Binding`.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using a `TreeView` instead of an `ItemsControl`?

Comment: Yes, I want to use `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and from what I've found on the Internet, it's only working with `TreeView`. But I will go with `ItemsControl` gladly if there is a way to make this work with it.

Comment: Are the Data Objects in your TreeView all of the same type? If they are, you could use an Implicit `DataTemplate` instead of a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

Comment: Well TreeView is binded to `XDocument` and uses `HierarchicalDataTemplate` so I get all the levels of document displayed. Data are hierarchical.

Comment: @Rachel: I think you are drawing the wrong conclusion here, it should be: If so you can apply the template via the `TreeView.ItemTemplate` otherwise it needs to be applied implicitly. In any case it needs to be a hierarchical datatemplate to support children.

Answer (score 4):

`TreeViewItems` lay out their own children, they each have their own panel, so you need to change the canvas on the `TreeView` and the items. To do this apply a style which changes the panel, either implicitly via resources or the `ItemContainerStyle`.

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TreeViewItem.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </TreeViewItem.ItemsPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```